# Which algorithm or idea to find the convex envelope of a set of curves?

Tags: c++, algorithm, computational-geometry, envelope

Let's define a curve as set of 2D points which can be computed to arbitrary precision. For instance, this is a curve:

[image]

A set of N intersecting curves is given (N can be arbitrarily large), like in the following image:

[image]

How to find the perimeter of the connected area (a bounding box is given if necessary) which is delimited by the set of curves; or, given the example above, the red curve? Note that the perimeter can be concave and it has no obvious parametrization.

[image]

- A starting point of the red curve can be given
- I am interested in efficient ideas to build up a generic algorithm however...
- I am coding in C++ and I can use any opensource library to help with this
- I do not know if this problem has a name or if there is a ready-made solution, in case please let me know and I will edit the title and the tags.

Additional notes:

- The solution is unique as in the region of interest there is only a single connected area which is free from any curve, but of course I can only compute a finite number of curves.
- The curves are originally parametrized (and then affine transformations are applied), so I can add as many point as I want. I can compute distances, lengths and go along with them. Intersections are also feasible. Basically any geometric operation that can be built up from point coordinates is acceptable.
- I have found that a similar problem is encountered when "cutting" gears eg. https://scialert.net/fulltext/?doi=jas.2014.362.367, but still I do not see how to solve it in a decently efficient way.

Comment: This is not a programming question. This is a math question.

Comment: _Maybe_ [Boost Geometry](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/index.html) can help with this.

Comment: I reviewed the FAQ before asking and found that "a software algorithm" is a good fit to ask here. And no, it is not a math question, it is a question of computational geometry (the tag already existed) and definitely a software problem.

Comment: @DarioP Would a correct answer to this question also be capable of producing a red line tracing the top, rather than the bottom, of this connected area? Why or why not?

Comment: This is not well defined. How can the algorithm differentiate between "sides". Are those curves really arbitrary sets of points? Can you e.g. compute a distance to this curve, can you even compute its length? Can you go along with it? What about computing intersections with lines? As it currently stands, I highly doubt it can be solved in any meaningful way. Is there a use case for this? Some kind of pathing problem? Is there any chance that they are circles?

Comment: @Patrick87 a "top" solution does not exists as the curves somehow extend to infinity.

Comment: @DarioP how can a bounding box be given if the curves extend to infinity?

Comment: @Patrick87 The bounding box is a region of interest. It cuts the curves at some point. In the bounding box the area that is free from any curve is connected, so there is only one solution.

Comment: @Quimby The curves are parametrized, so I can add as many point as I want. I can compute distances, lengths and go along with them. Intersections are also feasible. Basically any geometric operation is acceptable. I have found that a similar problem is encountered when "cutting" gears eg. https://scialert.net/fulltext/?doi=jas.2014.362.367, but still I do not see how to solve it in a decently efficient way.

Comment: @DarioP OK, so in the bounding box, the area bounded by the curve you want will be the one you can draw a horizontal line through without intersecting a curve in the box? Or, at any rate, we can assume the area bordering the perimeter you want will be indicated unambiguously (maybe the user clicks a region or something)?

Comment: @Patrick87 Yep, some kind of scan might work but the fact that the area can be concave complicates the problem. I also know a starting point of the red line, still building up from there is not obvious to me. I could quantize the plane and then it would be just a "flood fill" but I was interested in a more vectorial instead of "pixellian" solution. Mmmh maybe an adaptive mesh...

Comment: Similar to @Justin's comment regarding Boost Geometry, you might want to look at [CGAL](https://www.cgal.org/), in particular its Boolean_set_operations package.

Comment: Aren't you after an *offset curve* ? If yes, you are asking an XY question. Otherwise, your red curve is called the *envelope* of the pencil of curves.

Comment: Are the curves given in order ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question belongs to Mathematics

Comment: Sorry, but the question clearly off-topic as it doesn't deal with programming. Computational geometry is a branch of maths (algorithmics), and in several respects stays away from practical applications.

Comment: Here you go https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Envelope_2/index.html

Comment: @datjko That is pretty straightforward but unfortunately it only works if the curve is *weakly x-monotone* which is not the case and such a decomposition is not obvious in case of a convex shape :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the curves are given in order, you can find the pairwise intersections between successive curves. Depending on their nature, an analytical or numerical solution will do.

Then a first approximation of the envelope is the polyline through these points.

Another approximation can be obtained by drawing the common tangent to successive curves, and by intersecting those tangents pairwise. The common tangent problem is more difficult, anyway.

---

If the equations of the curves are known in terms of a single parameter, you can find the envelope curve by solving a differential equation, obtained by eliminating the parameter between the implicit equation of the curve and this equation differentiated wrt the parameter. You can integrate this equation numerically.

Comment: The second part is very interesting but it is not fully clear to me. So I have one parameter that runs along with the curve and another parameter which controls the affine transformations that generate the set of curves. How do I build a DE from there?

Comment: @DarioP: sorry, it is an ordinary equation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)

Comment: Wonderful, I should be able to go fully numerical then! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DarioP: I suspected that this was an XY problem.

Comment: The numerical solution for this is exactly what I am coding right now... although it is just a detail of a significantly larger research code.

Answer (score 1):

When I have got such problems (maths are not enough or are terribly tricky) I decompose each curve into segments.

Then, I search segment-segment intersections. For example, a segment in curve Ci with all of segments in curve Cj. Even you can replace a segment with its bounding box and do box-box intersection for quick discard, focusing in those boxes that have intersection.

This gives a rough aproximation of curve-curve intersections.

Apart from intersections you can search for max/min coordinates, aproximated also with segments or boxes.

Once you get a decent aproximation, you can refine it by reducing the length/size of segments and boxes and repeating the intersection (or max/min) checks.

Comment: mmmh, ok, so let's say that I know all the intersections on the plane. How to I choose the "most internal" ones given that the shape is convex? It would be quite easy for a concave shape (I just pick a point inside the area and ray trace from there until I hit the first curve for all the angles), but with convex shapes everything seems to break down :(

Answer (score 0):

You can have an approximate solution using the grids. First, find a bounding box for the curves. And then griding inside the bounding box. and then search over the cells to find the specified area. And finally using the number of cells over the perimeter approximate the value of the perimeter (as the size of the cells is known).

Comment: I don't think that this approach leads you anywhere. Or elaborate a little about "grinding" and the rest.

Comment: @YvesDaoust it was a typo. it is griding. It is a common approach in computational geometry!

Comment: I don't think it leads you anywhere. Or explain what you have in mind.